# What is the technical term for a document that contains the results of a final test for a specific product?

Tags: terminology, quality-engineering, industrial-engineering

Currently, I have to design a final test for a product. I want to summarize the results in a test report. The report is automatically generated and gives a summary (quantitatively) of which specifications are met and which are not met. If all the specifications are met, the test contains an "OK." Contained are product ID, diagrams, key figures, some explanatory paragraphs, and so on.

Does such a report have a specific technical term in quality engineering? With this term, I may be able to learn about best practices, etc., regarding such reports.

Comment: What do you mean by a "technical term" of a report? A report is a report.

Comment: "Test report" sound about right to me, granted that I'm not a quality engineer.

Comment: I realize that this sounds trivial, but maybe there is a term thats common among quality engineers - you could also name it product evaluation report, product evaluation sheet, ..., there are a lot of fancy (or not) words to describe such a document. _The name is only in so far important_ that I can search in the literature for best practices/guidelines.

Comment: Can you give more detail about your test?

Comment: @JohnH.K. I meant the nature of your test, your description could quite fit a wide range of reports for various tests, you could have for example dimension test report, hydrostatic test report, visual test report, Nitrogen leak test report ... etc.

Comment: @John H. K.That sounds more like a summary of test results, not really a test report.

Comment: @DLS3141 is there a difference :) ?

Comment: @Algo In my experience, sure. The summary just contains the Yes/No answers to the questions of did the DUT pass or fail the test per the pre-established success criteria. A report on the other hand will contain the details of a test or tests and data sufficient to assess performance and by what measure did the DUT exceed of fail to meet the requirements

Answer (score 2):

In most organizations, how you refer to a test in the report depends on the purpose of the test and in turn that will be reflected in the established document naming system. For example if the purpose of your test is validation, the report template would be named something like Validation Report - (Project XYZ) or something like that. Typically all of this should be set up in the quality management system.